# MPAndroidChart - Is it possible to set different markerViews for different dataSets?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a BarChart with two sets of data. One is blue and one is green.

Is it possible to have a blue Marker View for the blue dataset and a green Marker View for the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to have a different `MarkerView` for each `DataSet`.

However, it should be pretty **easy to change the background-color** of the marker depending on the dataset.

Just check for the dataset-index delivered by the `refreshContent(Entry e, int dataSetIndex)` method of the `MarkerView` and programmatically change the background-color of the `View` accordingly.

Comment: Hey, Philipp. I think I worded it wrong. You can change the `MarkerView` drawable programmatically through the same `refreshContent` method by instancing the layout for the `MarkerView` then using the `setBackground` / `setBackgroundDrawable` method.

Comment: In the new version `refreshContent()` no longer has `int dataSetIndex` as a parameter, how coould I solve the same problem?

Comment: Hey, for new version you can get the index by e.getX(). like dataList.get((int) entry.getX())

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the **Phillip's** answer this is something can be achieved in the new version of library:-

```
 override fun refreshContent(e: Entry, highlight: Highlight) {
        // This line will return you index eg, 
    if you have two datasets then below index will be returned as 0 and 1 and based on this you can identify and change color or style of your marker view
   val index = highlight.dataSetIndex
   super.refreshContent(e, highlight)
}
```